# SMS send to DATA Extension and subscribe

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a problem with how to manage sms unsubscribe from a keyword.
We have 3 DE for our SMS send in mobile connect, these DE are empowered by automation based on optin filter for every DE (Keyword=optin)

What i don't know is when sending, we attach the DE to the keyword, so is it possible to create a stop keyword for every keyword in order that customer can unsubscribe from our send (Newsletter, Sale...).

And also if the customer use the stop keyword for exemple to unsubscribe from our newsletter, where is updated in mobile connect? and how i can use this to update a optin field in sales cloud field?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Currently [**only Australia**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_sms_keyword_opt_out.htm&type=5) supports the opt-out from a specific Keyword, all other countries are opted out from *all* Keywords when Contact decides to send a (default or custom) STOP message.

With Marketing Cloud Connect, only the Email channel subscription status cross-synch is natively built in, meaning if you want to achieve similar solution with MobileConnect, you'll need to do it via either AMPScript in SMS response template (would work instantly) which would call [**UpdateSingleSalesforceObject**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm) function to update your specified field in Sales Cloud.

The other option is to store the response to a Data Extension and use Automation Studio and SSJS/AMPScript combination to update Sales Cloud records in batch. This is the method you'll also be using if you want to store SMS Send logs to Sales Cloud (similar to Individual Email Results).

Comment: Thanks Rain for your answer. Is it possible to have an exemple of "AMPScript in SMS response template (would work instantly) which would call UpdateSingleSalesforceObject function ".                                                                         And also, i have an issue my outbound sms when i receive it i can't answer my keybord is disabled and i can't send the stop answer is it normal?